present table (Descriptive analysis for continuous variable and absolute and relative frequencies also cumulative frequencies)
`install.packages`("stargazer")
library(stargazer)

stargazer(HD, 
      type = 'text',` min.max=F` , mean.sd = T,
      nobs = F, median = F, `iqr` = F,ci=T,
      ci = mean-(1.96 * standard_deviation),
      digits=1, align=T,
      title = "Descriptive Statistics")

Descriptive Statistics
Statistic Mean St. Dev.
AGE       62.7   8.2
WEIGHT    81.6   15.7
I need to present  CI with the mean and Sd in the same table
gave me
Error in stargazer(HD1, type = "text", min.max = F, mean.sd = T, ci = T,  :
formal argument "ci" matched by multiple actual arguments


